# Using IF statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

So i have 2 tables of this format,

**actual_data:**

```
ID,ROLL_NO,ADM_DT,FEES
1,9895987650,2017-11-14,10000
2,78578686,2017-11-10,130
3,434343,2017-11-15,20
```

**temp_data:**

```
ID,R_NO,FS,FT
1,9895987650,9000,F1
5,9895987650,5000,F2
3,78578686,150,F3
4,123456,24141,F4
```

I'm trying to create a stored-procedure here,

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE PROCEDURE `myproc`()
BEGIN
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM actual_data a, temp_data b
    WHERE a.ROLL_NO = b.R_NO 
        AND 
        ((b.FS >= a.FEES AND b.FT IS NOT NULL) 
        OR 
        (b.FS < a.FEES AND b.FT IS NOT NULL)); 
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

This will give me the following result:

```
ID,ROLL_NO,   ADM_DT,     FEES,ID, R_NO,FS,              FT
1, 9895987650,2017-11-14, 10000,   1,   9895987650,9000, F1
1, 9895987650,2017-11-14, 10000,   5,   9895987650,5000, F2
2, 78578686,  2017-11-10, 130,     3,   78578686,150,    F3
```

Now this is where i'm getting stuck.

What i would like to do is,

IF `b.FS >= a.FEES AND b.FT IS NOT NULL` is `TRUE`, i would like to `select R_NO,sum(FEES) GROUP BY R_NO HAVING sum(FEES) > 1000 ORDER BY R_NO` from the above query result.

ELSE IF `b.FS < a.FEES AND b.FT IS NOT NULL` is `TRUE`, i would like to `select R_NO,sum(FEES) GROUP BY R_NO HAVING sum(FEES) < 1000 ORDER BY R_NO` from the above query result.

Is this possible to do through a stored-procedure? If so, could I get some suggestions as to how this can be done? I'm a newbie when it comes to MySql, so kindly help me out.

Following is my effort:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `myproc` $$    
CREATE PROCEDURE `myproc`()
BEGIN
DECLARE firstCond INT;
DECLARE secondCond INT;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE firstTemp
SELECT a.*,b.R_NO,b.FS,b.FT FROM actual_data a, temp_data b
    WHERE a.ROLL_NO = b.R_NO AND (b.FS >= a.FEES AND b.FT IS NOT NULL);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE secondTemp
SELECT a.*,b.R_NO,b.FS,b.FT FROM actual_data a, temp_data b
    WHERE a.ROLL_NO = b.R_NO AND (b.FS < a.FEES AND b.FT IS NOT NULL);

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO firstCond FROM firstTemp;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO secondCond FROM secondTemp;

IF firstCond > 0 THEN
    SELECT f.ID,f.R_NO,SUM(f.FS) AS FS INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/MySqlProcFirstOutput1.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
    FROM firstTemp f 
        GROUP BY f.R_NO,f.ID 
            HAVING SUM(f.FS) > 50 
                ORDER BY f.R_NO,f.ID ASC;
END IF;
IF secondCond > 0 THEN
    SELECT s.ID,s.R_NO,SUM(s.FS) AS FS INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/Output2.txt' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    FROM secondTemp s 
        GROUP BY s.R_NO,s.ID 
            HAVING SUM(s.FS) > 50 
                ORDER BY s.R_NO,s.ID ASC;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

What I'd like to know is, whether this is the optimized way to do this?

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: @LelioFaieta: Indeed i have. Let me put it up in my question